# Default PowerShell to emitting UTF-8 instead of UTF-16?

Tags: powershell, redirection, character-encoding

By default, PowerShell in Windows seems to be outputting UTF-16 (e.g., if I do a simple `echo hello > hi.txt`, then `hi.txt` ends up in UTF-16).  I know that I can force this to my desired text encoding by instead doing `echo hello | out-file -encoding utf8 hi.txt`, but what I'd like is for that to just be the default when I use the redirection operator.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: thanks for the tip for an alternative, doing this from the terminal can be quicker than a text editor sometimes.

Comment: In Powershell 6.0, this has been rendered unnecessary - Powershell now defaults to UTF-8 without encoding for redirection. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4878

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using a .NET decompiler on the System.Management.Automation assembly (a.k.a. the "Microsoft Windows PowerShell Engine Core Assembly") reveals this code fragment:

```
// class: System.Management.Automation.RedirectionNode
private PipelineProcessor BuildRedirectionPipeline(string path, ExecutionContext context)
{
    CommandProcessorBase commandProcessorBase = context.CreateCommand("out-file");
    commandProcessorBase.AddParameter("-encoding", "unicode");
    if (this.Appending)
    {
        commandProcessorBase.AddParameter("-append", true);
    }
    commandProcessorBase.AddParameter("-filepath", path);
    ...
```

So, it looks pretty hardcoded to me.

FYI, this was on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 system with PowerShell 2.0 installed.

Comment: Still hard-coded in PowerShell 5 on Windows 10, unfortunately: `CommandParameterInternal.CreateParameterWithArgument(PositionUtilities.EmptyExtent, "Encoding", "-Encoding:", PositionUtilities.EmptyExtent, "Unicode", false, false);`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will do exactly what you're looking for, but you can try setting the environment variable as mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/)

```
$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Comment: I don't think `$OutputEncoding` is quite what I need; that's set to ASCII in PowerShell, and affects how things are *displayed*.  What I want to do is to change the format of text that's saved in a file, which (AFAICT) is different than what `$OutputEncoding` controls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default encoding of redirection operators (> and >>). The `Out-File` cmdlet is used behind the scenes when you use these operators.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

See [Powershell Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.3&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp#changing-the-default-encoding) for details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although as noted no longer an issue in Powershell 6+, this should be the accepted answer