# Is it possible to set "locale" of a Windows application to UTF-8?

Tags: windows, locale, code-page

We know there is an application called AppLocale, which can change the code page of non-Unicode applications, to solve text display problems.

But there is a program whose **right display code page** is UTF-8, which means **its text should be shown as UTF-8**, but instead Windows **displays it as the native code page** and makes the text unreadable. It seems funny, because there are almost all countries and regions, but without UTF-8. I think it is a bug, because the programmers may use English and ignore testing non-English text display issues. I don't think the producer will fix it and I wanna fix it myself.

Is it possible to set non-Unicode output as UTF-8 by using software like AppLocale? Default non-Unicode output is native code page? How can I set the native code page to UTF-8?

Comment: I've fixed most grammar issues for you but `there is almost include all countries and regions, but without UTF-8` is impossible to understand

Answer (score 9):

Previously it was not possible because

> Microsoft claimed a UTF-8 locale might break some functions (a possible example is `_mbsrev`) as they were written to assume multibyte encodings used no more than 2 bytes per character, thus until now code pages with more bytes such as GB 18030 (cp54936) and UTF-8 could not be set as the locale.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8

However there's a *"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"* checkbox since Windows 10 insider build 17035 for setting the locale code page to UTF-8

[image: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]

See also

- [Changing ansi and OEM code page in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1424009/241386)
- [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17035 Supports UTF-8 as ANSI](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15710685)

That said, the support is still buggy at this point

- [Freeze issue in Windows 10 1803 when use UTF-8 as default code page](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/71946/freeze-issue-in-windows-10-1803-when-use-utf-8-as-default-code-page)
- [when unicode beta support in windows 10 is turned on, add-ons fail to install](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/8599)
- [UTF-8 support for single byte character sets is beta in Windows and likely breaks a lot of applications not expecting this](https://wiert.me/2018/12/04/utf-8-support-for-single-byte-character-sets-is-beta-in-windows-and-likely-breaks-a-lot-of-applications-not-expecting-this-via-unicode-in-microsoft-windows-utf-8-wikipedia/)
- [Build fail with internal error in MSVC](https://gist.github.com/nazist/f97bf37045f5f465cb908a5e58d13824)

---

## Update:

Microsoft has also added the ability for programs to use the UTF-8 locale without even setting the UTF-8 beta flag above. You can use the [`/execution-charset:utf-8`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=vs-2019) or [`/utf-8`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019) options when compiling with MSVC or set the ActiveCodePage property in appxmanifest

You can also use UTF-8 locale in older Windows versions by linking with the appropriate C runtime

> Starting in Windows 10 build 17134 (April 2018 Update), the Universal C Runtime supports using a UTF-8 code page. This means that `char` strings passed to C runtime functions will expect strings in the UTF-8 encoding. To enable UTF-8 mode, use "UTF-8" as the code page when using `setlocale`. For example, `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8")` will use the current default Windows ANSI code page (ACP) for the locale and UTF-8 for the code page.
>
> ...
>
> To use this feature on an OS prior to Windows 10, such as Windows 7, you must use [app-local deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019#local-deployment) or link statically using version 17134 of the Windows SDK or later. For Windows 10 operating systems prior to 17134, only static linking is supported.
>
> [UTF-8 Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2019#utf-8-support)

Answer (score 0):

From what I read about Microsoft [AppLocale tool on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale), the tool can NOT change your code page to UTF-8. **It only works with Non-Unicode applications**, but UTF-8 is part of Unicode standard.

Under the hood, Unicode processing of non-ASCII characters greatly differs from non-Unicode one, so while it is possible to change between non-Unicode code pages (this is what AppLocale does) it is NOT possible to change between Unicode and non-Unicode without modification of the application made by its producer.

Comment: I know AppLocale can't work with Non-Unicode applications. But I don't think it need to convert encode. Only thing to do is to let the text content show correctly. The binary data is already correct UTF-8 text. For example, if you printf() a char array which content every byte of  a UTF-8 text, and  it will show as native encode (like iso-8859-1). If let the    default encode be UTF-8, then problem solved.

Comment: @KomeijiKuroko – please, if you wish, could you illustrate what you mean in your recent comment on some specific UTF-8 example?

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it here:
In Windows 10 17133 there is now a beta option to use UTF-8 for worldwide support. But it does not help with non-Unicode programs for me as of now, but it is placed on the pop-up where I can change the locale for non-Unicode programs.

So, maybe they are working on something to end the necessity of having to change the locale for non-Unicode programs.

Comment: Is there some source, link, goto?

Comment: What?  It is not clear what you are trying to say in this answer.  You should consider perhaps clarifying it.

Comment: I remember seeing this in a news feed somewhere before I saw this question so while I don't have a link either I believe it's true.