# Changing ansi and OEM code page in Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, control-panel, ascii

How to change ansi and OEM code page from 437 to 65001 in control panel? I have literally searched out whole control panel to change the code page but couldn't find it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is only supported starting with Windows 10.1804 (build 17134):

1. Open the "Region" control panel applet (run `intl.cpl`)
2. Select the "Administrative" tab
3. Open "Change system locale"
4. Select "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"