# Default character endcoding on Windows versions

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I know that in Western Europe and the US, CP-1252 is the default character encoding.

How about default character encoding in other windows version?

In addition, recently I hear that windows 8 use UTF-8 as default character encoding, is this correct?

Comment: The encoding is going to be appropriate for the default language.  Your asking a very broad question that doesn't have a single answer.  Where did you hear that Windows 8 uses UTF-8 character encoding?[Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Additional Information](http://superuser.com/questions/221593/windows-7-utf-8-and-unicode)

Comment: Is there any where has these information, like an MSDN page? That's enough for the answer.

Comment: Feel free to do your own searches.  I had no problem finding the information myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows intrinsically uses the UTF-16 encoding. The “default encodings”, or “default codepages” in Microsoft terminology, are just legacy encoding that are used by many old programs. E.g., in Notepad, the default encoding when saving a file is “ANSI”, which (rather misleadingly) denotes the default codepage (but Notepad internally works with UTF-16).

The system locale determines the default codepage. The page [Windows Locale Codes - Sortable list](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp) shows the mapping and is probably reliable. (I was unable to find a Microsoft page on this.)

In particular, web browsers tend to use the default codepage so determined as the encoding of a web page, if encoding information is not available. In reality, it’s more complicated. In HTML5 LC, section [Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) describes (and prescribes) the process, and it also contains a mapping table that largely reflects the Windows mappings from locales to codepages.